# Auto-Deploy on IIS from Github?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, github, deployment

I found a way using a .php page to auto deploy, quick and dirty, using a Post-Receive URL.  So you put the following into a page on your site:

```
<?php `git pull`; ?>
```

Put that page's URL into GiHub and bang, auto deploy.  Works great.  Is there something similar or equivalent for .ASP?  I have a site running on IIS 6.0 and it would be great to do an ASP equivalent.

I through about installing PHP on the IIS server, seems like a waste for just a sigle page and would open me up to PHP security and patching issue.  Rather just use some .ASP code.

Could find what I need via Google, GitHub:Gists, or iis.net.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about PHP, except it's a scripting language. But ASP.NET projects need to be built. Anyway, you can simplify the processes by using Paas platforms such as [AppHarbor](https://github.com/blog/961-deploy-to-appharbor-from-github) (or Azure, as Kelly mentioned).

Comment: AppHarbor is a PAAS provider...  This is an existing site on an existing server, rather not move providers just for deployment.  That's good to know for any future needs

Comment: With asp.net you can use azure to auto pull and deploy latest changes. There are more supported scenarios as well.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you need to install the git on your server.
then run the git command from your asp page.
if you using asp classic, try something like this:

```
<%
    Dim oShell
    Set oShell = Server.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    oShell.Run "git pull"
    Set oShell = Nothing
%>
```

it will done the same job as PHP.

if you looking for asp.net version.
Ive a simple project on github:
https://github.com/tshwangq/IISDeploy

Answer (score 0):

Using the Webhook-URL's service hook, formerly known as Post-Receive-URL's, from GitHub in PHP is easy. Just as you say. Basically, the **git pull** command is integrated in most Apache environments. This is not the case with ASP.NET.

Simply put: with PHP you only need to copy the appropriate files from GitHub > Webserver. On the other hand, ASP.NET (or most .NET environments) needs  **the project to be compiled** first. Therefor, installing PHP on your IIS alone will not get the job done.

So, in order to make this work for you ASP.NET project you need to:

1. Create a consumer for the [Post-Receive hook](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks) that downloads the latest files
2. [Compile the files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx) on the webserver
3. Copy the build results to the desired folder

Unfortunately, I haven't come across a working example yet.

Comment: Some of us use IIS7 with uncompiled languages (Php, Asp Classic).  It would be useful to know how you can do a Git Pull automatically